# select minimum quantity where productID =1

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, t-sql

i am working on asp .net mvc3. i have following table

[image]

i want to select minimum quanity where ProductID=1

please help to find out the exact query for above requirement.

Comment: in database using sql or where?

Comment: your questions is ambagious... do you meant to say your development environment is asp.net mvc, you are trying to retrieve a product with minimum quantity where product id is 1 from an SQL data store?

Comment: yes yes my database is stored in sql server. i am using entity framework to retrieve data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: Use Min method:

```
 var results = db.ProductTable.Where(r => r.productId == 1).Min(r=> r.Quantity);
```

I'm not sure how you are accessing your data or where it is stored but something like this:

SQL:

```
SELECT MIN(Quantity) FROM table where ProductId=1
```

LINQ is something like this:

```
var minQuantity = from P In Products
                    Where P.ProductId = 1
                    select Min(P.Quantity)
```

Comment: sir , i use these type of query in my controller class.             var results  = db.ProductTable.Where(r => r.whereId == 1);   but i dont know how to handle MIN in these queries. so how can write above statement for "select minimum quantity where ProductId=1"

Answer (score 2):

```
context.table.where(q=>q.productid=1).Select(k => k).Min(k=>k.quantity)
```

it's important to note that min is a client side function meaning it will execute min algo on the records returned in your program not in SQL which is not a recommended approach if by any means your dataset is a big collection then it will retrieve all those records and then will find the minimum value to return.

[you can read more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535108.aspx)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "is a client side function"  The Linq processor will generator the SQL you would expect it to generate, and the only traffic back to the client will be the scalar value.  Also, the Select ,in this case, is not necessary, just hang the Min off the Where.